# Rendering images and voxelizing the images

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing

I am using the shapenet dataset. From this dataset, I have 3d models in .obj format. I rendered the images of these 3d models using pyrender library which gives me an image like this :
[image]

Now I am using raycasting to voxelize this image. The voxel model I get is something like below :

[image]

I am not able to understand why I am getting the white or light brown colored artifacts in the boundary of the object.

The reason I could come up with was maybe the pixels at the boundary of the object contain two colors, so when I traverse the image as numpy array, I get an average of these two colors which gives me these artifacts. But I am not sure if this is the correct reason.

If anyone has any idea about what could be the reason, please let me know

Comment: Is that related to AI? Please explain

Comment: This is off topic. @nbro

Comment: I checked on google for the forums where I can ask questions about computer vision. This forum came up citing the reason that since "computer-vision" is available as one of the tags, questions related to this can be posted here

Comment: Please refer to the help center for questions that is on topic. https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The computer vision tag in this case means this: `For questions related to computer vision, which is an interdisciplinary scientific field (which can e.g. use image processing techniques) that deals with how computers can be made to gain high-level understanding from digital images or videos. For example, image recognition (that is, the identification of the type of objects in an image) is a computer vision problem` This is defined in the tag wiki of the computer-vision tag. Your question clearly does not fit the description of the tag.

Comment: @mascot If you can put this problem in the context of computer vision, then this question may be on-topic here. Maybe try reformulating your question.